# How to find hidden elements using jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to find how many items with a class are visible but I'm getting weird results from my jquery selector

[image]

There's 5 elements total with only one where I removed the style

Comment: $(".link-container:hidden").length

Comment: Please [edit] your code to include a [mcve] in the question, as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be
>   visible, since they still consume space in the layout. - [jQuery API Docs.](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector)

So, instead you should give these elements a `display: none;` rule or set their `height` to 0 in order to make them catchable by the `:hidden` jQuery selector.

Comment: I'm using jquery.hide()/.show() to set the visibility. What's a better way?

Comment: but `jQuery`'s hide/show methods use the `display` property to hide/show the element(s). To make `.link-container` elements catchable by the `:hidden` `jQuery` selector, you could play on their `display` property.